# Java Process Builder not executing multiple commands

Tags: java, linux, sleep, processbuilder

Hi a Java newbie here.

I am currently building a Java application that executes multiple linux commands with Java Process builder.

I am planning to execute a shell scipt, and since it this shell script is an external program that takes about a second to fully execute, let the process sleep for a second and write the result into a txt file.

This is an external program and it must take in "q" to exit the program, so I finally need to type in q in the terminal.

I have gotten help on this community before and the code I constructed with that help is as follows.

```
public static void Linux(String fileName){

try {
  File dir = new File("/usr/local/bin");
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "./test_elanprv2.2.sh > \"$1\"; sleep 1; q", "_", fileName + ".txt"});
  System.out.println("wrote text");
  pb.directory(dir);
  Process start = pb.start();
  start.destroy();
}catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("failed to write text");
}
```

The process builder does create a txt file but it seems to be empty, and no matter how long I set the sleep to, the programs seems to instanly return the print statement.

It would really be appreciated if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should use [redirectOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)) instead of making the bash command do it.  And don’t call start.destroy() right after starting your process;  let the process finish, by calling `start.waitFor()`, first.

Comment: @VGR Thank you for your feedback. However would there be a way to enter q into the same process, as I need to turn the program off after the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @VGR, try using redirectOutput

```
public static void Linux(String fileName){

try {
   File dir = new File("/usr/local/bin");
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "./test_elanprv2.2.sh");
   File output = new File("_", fileName + ".txt");
   pb.redirectOutput(output);
   System.out.println("wrote text");
   pb.directory(dir);
   Process start = pb.start();
   start.destroy();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.out.println("failed to write text");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! But would there be a way to input "q" in the same process? I have tried manually exiting the program with cntrl + c, but that seems to cause some error to the program, and a q should be typed in to exit the program properly.

Comment: You can use `getOutputStream()` on the process to get an output stream that you can write to in order to pipe data to the process's stdin. If you write `"q\n"` to it, it should be the same as the user typing in `q` and hitting enter.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for your feedback, but I'm a little unclear on how to execute what you said. I tried start.getOutPutStream("q\n") but it seems the method does not accept strings.

Comment: @Adam It takes no parameters and returns an OutputStream. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ for how to work with IO streams in Java

Answer (score 0):

Most of your issues are due to a misunderstanding of how processes work.  These concepts are not Java concepts;  you would have the same issues in any other language.

First, you are destroying your process before it runs, and possibly before it even gets started.  This is because `pb.start()` starts the process, and then you immediately destroy it without giving it a chance to complete.

You shouldn’t need to destroy the process at all.  Just let it finish:

```
Process start = pb.start();
start.waitFor();
```

All processes have their own *standard input* and *standard output.*  Again, this is not a Java concept;  this has been a fundamental feature in Unix and Windows operating systems for a long time.

Normally, when a process prints information by writing it to its standard output.  That is in fact what Java’s `System.out.println` does.  In Unix shells (and in Windows), the `>` character redirects the standard output of a process to a file;  the program still writes to its standard output, without ever knowing that the operating system is sending that output to a destination other than the terminal.  Since it’s a fundamental operating system function, Java can do it for you:

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
    new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "./test_elanprv2.2.sh");
pb.redirectOutput(new File(fileName + ".txt"));
```

Similarly, when a process wants to take input, it normally does so by reading from its standard input.  This is not the same as executing another command.  When you do this:

```
./test_elanprv2.2.sh > "$1"; sleep 1; q
```

You are not sending `q` to the shell script.  The above commands **wait for the shell script to finish,** then execute a sleep, then try to execute a program named `q` (which probably doesn’t exist).

Since the test_elanprv2.2.sh shell script probably accepts commands by reading its standard input, you want to send the `q` command to the standard input of that process:

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
    new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "./test_elanprv2.2.sh");
pb.redirectOutput(new File(fileName + ".txt"));

Process start = pb.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);

try (Writer commands = new OutputStreamWriter(start.getOutputStream())) {
    commands.write("q\n");
}

// Caution: Call this AFTER writing commands.  You don't want to write
// to the standard input of a process that has already finished!
start.waitFor();
```